# Why does Truffle create contract when tests contains no transactions?

Tags: truffle, testing

I tried running tests that were not sending any transactions and ran into two errors that to me make no sens : an authentification error and, when the account has been unlocked, a block gas limit error (Error: Exceeds block gas limit).

This prompted me to look at the transaction that Truffle sends when running tests. The code of the test is the following :

```
contract('Testing truffle', function(){
    it('does nothing', function(){
        assert(true);
    });
});
```

Using a local geth node connected to Ethereum testnet, I can see six transactions being sent :

[image]

Three of them seems to be contract creation and the others are transactions to the first created contract (0x288fb9423026fa441b85d02028838e7756497c61).

Can someone tell me what that is about ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tests run your migrations. By default there's a Migrations contract handling the migrations and it's created at the start of the tests.

For more information: http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/migrations